# Reading and Writing UUID, images, audio, and video while implenting Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

I would like to implement `Parcelable` in a custom class I have written so I can pass entire objects from fragment to fragment. Each object will contain a UUID, a String, an image, a video, audio, or some combination of the four. I'm also considereing using `EventBus`, but since I am new to Android and would like to learn, I'm trying to implement `Parcelable` on my own for now.

I'm using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) example on Google's Developer guides, but I can't find the methods to read/write a UUID, an image, a video, or audio. For example, there is `readInt`, `readString`, `readLong`, etc. - are there comparable methods for what I want to do?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no Java class for "audio". There is no Java class for "video". Please explain what "an image, a video, audio" mean, in terms of actual Java classes.

Comment: Sorry about that. I haven't gotten to coding those parts yet, so I'm not sure. I believe the image will be a `Bitmap`. I'm not sure what  classes Android uses for videos and audio, but I will probably try to follow Google's Developer guidelines as closely as possible, [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/index.html)

Comment: @pez You probably shouldn't try to parcel those. Keep them on disk somewhere, and maybe use `FileDescriptor` to reference the data and read it back in on construction (something like that, anyway).

Comment: @kcoppock I thought I might run into those problems. [This](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/using-android-parcel) example explains that trying to pass a `Bitmap` image is not a good idea. I'll probably have to look at other solutions.

Comment: Bear in mind that a `Parcelable` needs to be *very small*. It is passed across process boundaries, and there are limits on those "binder transactions" in terms of the total size. For example, if your vision was to use a `Parcelable` in an `Intent` extra, the total size of an `Intent`, including all of its extras, needs to be under 1MB.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. I'll look into `EventBus` and other solutions to pass this information around my app.

Answer (score 4):

So there are two ways you can do this. The easiest way is to just use `writeSerializable()` since `UUID` is `Serializable`. It can be slow, but probably not a big deal unless you're doing it thousands of times:

```
parcel.writeSerializable(mUuid);

mUuid = (UUID) parcel.readSerializable();
```

Alternatively, you can grab the most and least significant bits as two longs:

```
parcel.writeLong(mUuid.getMostSignificantBits());
parcel.writeLong(mUuid.getLeastSignificantBits());

mUuid = new UUID(parcel.readLong(), parcel.readLong());
```

Comment: Actually, the UUID is the easy part, as there is `ParcelUuid` that makes a `Parcelable` wrapper around a `UUID`. I'm trying to figure out what the OP means by the rest...

Comment: Wow, I totally skipped over those last three and went straight to UUID. Not sure why. :p

Comment: I didn't know about `ParcelUuid`. Looking at the implementation it's just doing the second route anyway though (writing out two longs).